# How to correctly use @task.kubernetes() decorator to import third-party dependencies?

Tags: python, kubernetes, airflow, airflow-2.x

I have an Airflow DAG task that I want to run on K8s pod. Here's an example

```py
from mymodule import process_data # this is my module import
from decouple import AutoConfig # this is externally installed dependency 

@dag(
    "model_trainer",
    start_date=datetime(2023, 1, 1),
    catchup=False,
    schedule=None,
)
def pipeline():
    @task.kubernetes(image="python")
    def fetch_data():
        return process_data()
```

Now running this code (`pipeline().test()`) gives me

`NameError: name 'process_data' is not defined`

Which is understandable because I'm using python image and there's no process_data. Neither it has the externally installed dependencies. My question is, what is the best way to deal with such scenario? Do I create my own image that has the installed dependencies and then import my modules inside the function?